# I have lost my wallet seed phrase

Tags: wallets

Pls can I get my phrase though my contract address or which app can I used to get my full details with contract address back or get my phrase back any help pls

Comment: Pls I need a help to get it back

Answer (score 0):

If you have lost your seed phrase there is no way to get it back.

This is the self-custodial part of crypto - you are responsible for securing the funds yourself.

Comment: Pls I no that you can find away for me to get it back pls and pls help or any app you can gave to me to see all my details so that I can get the seed phrase back I need a help pls.